# How to use `typedef NS_ENUM` to return `float` values?

Tags: objective-c, enums, floating-point, int, typedef

In the code (*below*) `LINE_WIDTH` is declared a `typedef` for enumeration where the names Large, Medium, Small and Hairline are `int` constants.

```
    typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, LINE_WIDTH)
    {
        LINE_WIDTH_Large,
        LINE_WIDTH_Medium,
        LINE_WIDTH_Small,
        LINE_WIDTH_Hairline    
    };
```

How can I use these `int` values to return `float` values of Large (1.5), Medium (1.0), Small (0.5) and Hairline (0.25) ?

*NOTE: a simpler version of my [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44233973/2348597) that led no where despite [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/707572/2348597) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8867169/2348597)*

Comment: rmaddy, yes, but as the answer in the last link (above) shows the integer types can be used to access an array. And I cannot work out what I need to do to apply that here.

Comment: That answer doesn't apply here. That is for dealing with a range. I updated my answer with a 2nd option. The 1st option is still better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't support non-integer enum values. Your only option is to provide code that converts the enum value to a `float` value.

One option is to create a simple function such as:

```
float LINE_WIDTH_float(LINE_WIDTH width);
```

Put that in the same .h as the enum declaration. Then add the following to some appropriate .m or .c file:

```
float LINE_WIDTH_float(LINE_WIDTH width) {
    switch (width) {
        case LINE_WIDTH_Large:
            return 1.5f;
        case LINE_WIDTH_Medium:
            return 1.0f;
        case LINE_WIDTH_Small:
            return 0.5f;
        case LINE_WIDTH_Hairline:
            return 0.25f;
        default:
            return 0.0f;
    }
}
```

So somewhere you have an enum value:

```
LINE_WIDTH someWidth = LINE_WIDTH_Medium;
float width = LINE_WIDTH_float(someWidth);
```

Another option would be to define an array of `float`.

In the same .h as the enum add:

```
extern float *LINE_WIDTH_float;
```

Then in some appropriate .m or .c, you can add:

```
float *LINE_WIDTH_float = { 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.25 };
```

Then to use this you can do:

```
LINE_WIDTH someWidth = LINE_WIDTH_Medium;
float width = LINE_WIDTH_float[someWidth];
```

Note that this is less safe than the first approach. It will likely crash if your enum value is set to something other than a valid enum value or if you add a new enum value but forget to update the values in the array.

Comment: rmaddy, your second option was where I was heading but I just finished testing your first option. It’s perfect! All four variables work in various classes throughout the project. e.g. `ring.layer.borderWidth = LINE_WIDTH_float(LINE_WIDTH_Large);` I'm starting to owe you quite a few beers! This has to be the accepted answer.

Comment: @CRD Thanks - too much Swift lately.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift you can use type double for enums

```
enum Constants: Double {
    case π = 3.14159
    case e = 2.71828
    case φ = 1.61803398874
    case λ = 1.30357
}
```

To know much about practical usage of enums in swift please refer https://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples/

Comment: AnshaD, is there an equivalent in Objective C ?

Comment: AnshaD, I gave this +1 because I didn't know this and it will be handy when my project moves to Swift. Thanks